# Streaming a list of objects as a single response, with progress reporting

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, servicestack, protobuf-net

My application has an "export" feature. In terms of functionality, it works like this:

When the user presses the "Export" button (after configuring the options etc.), the application first runs a relatively quick query that determines the IDs of all the objects need to be exported. Then, for each object, it executes a calculation that can a relatively long time to finish (up to 1s per object). While this is happening, the user is watching a progress bar -- which is easy to render, since we know the expected number of objects, as well as how many objects have been processed so far.

I would like to move this functionality to the webservice, for all the usual reasons. However, one additional wrinkle in this process is that our users often have a lot of network latency. Thus, I can't afford to make 1000 requests if I have 1000 rows to process.

What I'd like to do is to return a custom stream from the service. I can write the row count into the first 4 bytes of the stream. The client will read these 4 bytes, initialize the progress bar, and then proceed to read the stream and deserialize them on the fly, updating the progress bar as it deserializes each one. Meanwhile, the server will write objects into the stream as they become available.

To make matters more interesting, since I'm sending back a long list of objects, I would really like to use protobuf-net to reduce the overhead. Hence, I have several questions:

- Is what I am planning to do even possible ? Does it make sense, or is there a better way ?
- How can I return a custom stream from a ServiceStack service ?
- When I am deserializing a stream of objects on the client side, how can I get some sort of a notification as each object is deserialized ? I need it to update the progress bar.

I found this answer, which kind of does what I want, but doesn't truly address my questions: [Lazy, stream driven object serialization with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621902/lazy-stream-driven-object-serialization-with-protobuf-net)

EDIT: I should have mentioned that my client is a desktop C# application, which uses ServiceStack and protobuf.net .

Comment: Search for "long poll".

Comment: EDIT: I should have mentioned that my client is a desktop C# application, which uses ServiceStack and protobuf.net .

Comment: You could also implement this as a Server Sent Events stream.  A worker process on the server would tick over and as objects are finished processing, "push" them down to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend paging the result set over multiple requests (i.e. using Skip/Take) instead of trying to return a stream of results which will require custom response, custom serialization and custom clients to consume the streaming response. This is a more stateless approach which is more suitable over HTTP where each query can be cached independently, better support for retrying i.e. if there was an error with one of the requests you can retry from the last successful response (i.e. instead of having to download the entire request again) and better debuggability and introspection with existing HTTP tools.

### Custom Streaming response

Here's an example that shows how to return an Observable StreamWriter and a custom Observable client to consume the streamed response: https://gist.github.com/bamboo/5078236
It uses custom JSON serialization to ensure that each element is written before it's flushed to the stream so the client consuming the stream can expect each read to retrieve an entire record. This custom serialization would be more difficult if using a binary serializer like protocol buffers.

### Returning Binary and Stream responses in ServiceStack

The [ImageService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/Test/Test.ServiceInterface/ImageService.cs) shows different ways of returning binary or Stream responses in ServiceStack:

#### Returning a Stream in a HttpResult

```
public object Any(ImageAsStream request)
{
    using (var image = new Bitmap(100, 100))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.Clear(request.Format.ToImageColor());
        }
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, request.Format.ToImageFormat());
        return new HttpResult(ms, request.Format.ToImageMimeType()); 
    }
}
```

#### Returning raw byte[]

```
public object Any(ImageAsBytes request)
{
    using (var image = new Bitmap(100, 100))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.Clear(request.Format.ToImageColor());
        }
        using (var m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, request.Format.ToImageFormat());
            var imageData = m.ToArray(); //buffers
            return new HttpResult(imageData, request.Format.ToImageMimeType());
        }
    }
}
```

The examples above show how you can add additional metadata to the HTTP Response by wrapping the `Stream` and `byte[]` responses in a `HttpResult`, but if you prefer you can also return the `byte[]`, `Stream` or `IStreamWriter` responses directly.

#### Writing directly to the Response Stream

```
public void Any(ImageWriteToResponse request)
{
    using (var image = new Bitmap(100, 100))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.Clear(request.Format.ToImageColor());
        }

        base.Response.ContentType = request.Format.ToImageMimeType();
        image.Save(base.Response.OutputStream, request.Format.ToImageFormat());
        base.Response.Close();
    }
}
```

#### Returning a Custom Result

```
public object Any(ImageAsCustomResult request)
{
    var image = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        g.Clear(request.Format.ToImageColor());
        return new ImageResult(image, request.Format.ToImageFormat()); 
    }
}
```

Where you can write to the response stream directly by implementing `IStreamWriter.WriteTo()`:

```
//Your own Custom Result, writes directly to response stream
public class ImageResult : IDisposable, IStreamWriter, IHasOptions
{
    private readonly Image image;
    private readonly ImageFormat imgFormat;

    public ImageResult(Image image, ImageFormat imgFormat = null)
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.imgFormat = imgFormat ?? ImageFormat.Png;
        this.Options = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { HttpHeaders.ContentType, this.imgFormat.ToImageMimeType() }
        };
    }

    public void WriteTo(Stream responseStream)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, imgFormat);
            ms.WriteTo(responseStream);
        } 
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.image.Dispose();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }
}
```